# Promise.resolve internal referencing confusion

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I am learning JS and came across this snippet in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve)

```js
var promise1 = Promise.resolve(123);

promise1.then(function(value) {
  console.log(value);
  // expected output: 123
});
```

If i modify the above snippet and pass console.log as a *then* parameter i get the same result.

```js
var promise1 = Promise.resolve(123);

promise1.then(console.log);
```

I would like to know about the second code how :

1. The value *123* is being internally referenced as i have not passed it as a parameter of *then*.
2. When i pass console.log without calling it " *console.log(value)* ", how is it executing and in addition logging *123*.

Comment: This is nothing specific to promises. You can simply pass any function reference to anything that requires a function, e.g., `arr.map(x => x*2)` is the same as `fn = x => x*2; arr.map(fn)`. If you have `function(value) { console.log(value)}` that's really just the same thing as simply passing `console.log` as reference.

Comment: `window.console.log` is a function which you pass to the promise as a callback to `then` that is subsequently passed the value from the `.resolve()` as the value i.e. `.then(function(value) {` so `value` is `123` which you passed in  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

Comment: Seems to me as though the thing you're having trouble with is the concept of callback functions. Take a look at [MDN's explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Promises have their own state, consisting of:

- Whether they're *pending* or *settled* (*fulfilled*, or *rejected*)
- If fulfilled, their *fulfillment value*
- If rejected, their *rejection reason*

[`Promise.resolve`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) is a utility function that creates a promise that is *resolved to* what you pass it. Since you're passing it a simple value, it gets fulfilled with that value, which becomes part of its state. (As opposed to a simple value, you could resolve it to a *thenable* [loosely, a promise], in which case it would be fulfilled or rejected when that other thenable fulfilled or rejected.)

Later, when you attach a fulfillment handler with `then`, it calls your handler with that fulfillment value (even if it's already fulfilled). With a real Promise, that call is always asynchronous (even if the promise already fulfilled when you call `then`). (With a thenable, it may or may not be asynchronous.)

These terms are laid out in the [Promises/A+ spec](https://promisesaplus.com). See also Domenic Denicola's [*States and Fates*](https://github.com/domenic/promises-unwrapping/blob/master/docs/states-and-fates.md) page.

Looping back to your questions:

> 1. The value 123 is being internally referenced as i have not passed it as a parameter of then.

Yes, it's stored within he promise as state information (fulfillment value).

> 2. When i pass console.log without calling it " console.log(value) ", how is it executing and in addition logging 123.

`console.log` is a function. Functions are first-class objects in JavaScript, which means you can pass them around. It happens that `console.log` doesn't care what its `this` value is, so you can get away with just passing the function without binding a `this` value to it.

Fundamentally, the `then` is doing the same thing `example` is here:

```js
function example(handler) {
    // `setTimeout` is NOT really used by the promise implementation;
    // promises queue a "promise job" instead
    setTimeout(() => {
        handler(123);
    }, 0);
}

example(console.log);
```

---

*[About my note on `setTimeout` above: `setTimeout` is **not** really what they use. Instead, they queue a "promise job" (aka "microtask"). All JavaScript code runs are part of a job from a job queue. All of the promise jobs queued by a script job (aka "task") are run when the script job is done (before the next script job is picked up from the script job queue, even if that script job was been waiting longer than the promise jobs have).]*

Comment: Your answer really helped me alot and is quite thorough. Have bookmarked your blog. :-) Could you please suggest some good resources for more in depth info on JS like the ones you provided in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. The statement `console.log` puts a reference to the function `log` living on the `console` object on the stack.
2. The signature of `Promise.prototype.then` tells that it needs a function (or a reference to a function), that may optionally consume values that are resolved by the promise before in the chain.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to pass a function as parameter you have to pass it by name

you can pass any function to promise callback and it will take the param value from promise and pass it to your function s

```
function s (value) {
  console.log(value);
  // expected output: 123
}
promise1.then(s);
```

console.log function is the same like upper s function but it's inside console global object

```
var console = {
   log: function(...params){ //do ... }
}
```